# How to clear BufferedReader if it isn't empty [Java/Android]

Tags: java, android, arraylist, bufferedreader, readline

I don't understand how to clear a BufferedReader. When I push button in Activity, the variable is set to 1 or 2. Depend on number change file in BufferedReader. When I push second time in buffer will be two files. How to tell BR to clear buffer before second will be upload. And vice versa, of course.

```
public List<String> getQuestionLinesList() {

            String line;
            List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            Log.d(TAG, " Trying to get resourses");
            Resources res = context.getResources();


            try {

                    if (selectedBox == 1) {

                        bufferedQuestions = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res.openRawResource(R.raw.questions_list)));

                    } else if (selectedBox == 2) {

                        bufferedQuestions = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res.openRawResource(R.raw.questions_list_art)));

                    }


                Log.d(TAG, "number i = " + Integer.toString(selectedBox));

                while ((line = bufferedQuestions.readLine()) != null) {
                    lines.add(line);
                    Log.d(LINETAG, line);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return lines;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using a local variable in your method for BufferedReader not "bufferedQuestions" that you probably declared like a field in the class where that method : "getQuestionLinesList"  belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Add a carriage/ \n at the end of your files, then readLine() should be able to clear your BufferedReader.

[JavaDocs for BufferedRead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) which states

> ```
>   public String readLine()
>   throws IOException
> ```
>
> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.
>
> Returns:
>   A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

Comment: BufferedReader will be cleared before i could use it